# extracting images from an .xml and .img file combination

Tags: xml, image

Trying to extract images from a img file in combination with a xml file that contains offsets and lengths, need some insite on the path that is given in the xml element.
If you have some insight it would be greatly appreciated.
I am thinking the file name requires a full path in order to obtain the full images.

Have tried changing the file name to have a path.
Have tried opening the img file to where windows could open a virtual optical file to view.
Have tried other applications where I thought i could obtain an image from the img file only
Im exhausted

Comment: Share your code, and which programming language you're using. What went wrong, and how did it go wrong? Incorrect results? Errors?